# Android maintain mask across activities

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android app that needs to show a loading mask (e.g. ProgressDialog) when the login process starts, through the transition of a startIntent to the next activity, and then finally hide once that new activity has finished loading some setup data.

Is there a way to maintain a mask being shown across activity boundaries like that?  The dialog seems to be bound to an activity context, so right now I have to show/hide it on each activity, so it flickers and looks clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Fragments inside a single activity instead of two separate activities. This will allow you to show the progress during the transition.

Comment: It's crossed my mind, but would require completely re-architecting the application, and since it's part of a framework of sorts, would also break other apps using it :(